# PHPUnit/DbUnit "Too many connections"

Tags: mysql, pdo, phpunit, dbunit

While running PHPUnit tests, a lot of connections are created but not closed.
I can see this in

```
mysql> show processlist;
```

In my database class I create a db connection by implementing PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase#getConnection().

I make sure that in the teardown the connection gets closed. See snippet:

```
<?php

abstract class My_Tests_DatabaseTestCase extends \PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase
{

    static private $pdo = null;
    private $conn = null;

    /**
     * @throws RuntimeException
     * @return PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DB_IDatabaseConnection
     */
    final public function getConnection()
    {
        $iniFilePath = __DIR__ . '/../../../db-config.ini';
        $iniFile = parse_ini_file($iniFilePath, true);

        $dsn = "mysql:dbname=".$iniFile['phpunit']['dbname'].";host=".$iniFile['phpunit']['host'];
        if ( $this->conn === null ) {
            if ( self::$pdo == null ) {
                self::$pdo = new \PDO($dsn, $iniFile['phpunit']['user'], $iniFile['phpunit']['password']);
            }
            $this->conn = $this->createDefaultDBConnection(self::$pdo, $iniFile['phpunit']['dbname']);
        }
        return $this->conn;
    }

    protected function getSetUpOperation()
    {
        return new \PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_Operation_Composite(array(
            new \TestsExtensions\TruncateDatabaseOperation(),
            \PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_Operation_Factory::INSERT()
        ));
    }

    protected function getTearDownOperation() {
        return \PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_Operation_Factory::TRUNCATE();
    }

    protected function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $em = \ORM\Provider::getInstance()->getEntityManager(\ORM\Provider::DEFAULT_ID);
        $em->clear();
    }

    protected function tearDown()
    {
        parent::tearDown();
        $em = \ORM\Provider::getInstance()->getEntityManager(\ORM\Provider::DEFAULT_ID);
        $em->getConnection()->close();
        if ($this->conn) {
            $this->conn->close();
        }
    }
}
```

Debugging showed that the connections were closed, but the processlist showed them with status "sleep". 
The amount of connections rises until I get the "too many connections" error.

I do not want to increase the number of connections. I want to close the connection.

What can I modify to make this happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Snippet from [PDO Connection management](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php):

> Upon successful connection to the database, an instance of the PDO
>   class is returned to your script. The connection remains active for
>   the lifetime of that PDO object. To close the connection, you need to
>   destroy the object by ensuring that all remaining references to it are
>   deleted--you do this by assigning NULL to the variable that holds the
>   object. If you don't do this explicitly, PHP will automatically close
>   the connection when your script ends.

Don't store the PDO or set it to null in the teardown:

Remove `static private $pdo = null;`

or

```
protected function tearDown()
{
    parent::tearDown();
    $em = \ORM\Provider::getInstance()->getEntityManager(\ORM\Provider::DEFAULT_ID);
    $em->getConnection()->close();
    if ($this->conn) {
        $this->conn->close();
    }
    self::$pdo = null;
}
```

I don't think you need to store the PDO if you are going to pass it into the PHPUnit DB connection

Comment: The problem was $this->conn->close(). It doesn't exist. Looking at the API of PDO in php.net made it clear that it doesn't have a close method. Why I'm not getting a fatal error I don't know. $this->conn = null does the trick. Your answer on self::pdo = null brought me there. +1.

Comment: @eddy147 - in light of that success, perhaps consider accepting this answer.